# Failed to load resource : server responded with status 400

Tags: solr

I'm working on a project in which the server is written in Java language and based on Solr. Well, I'm now facing issues with queries : it was not happening before. Here screenshot of error :

[image]

Is it happening due to Solr is got any new update ?

Answer (score 0):

It's from solr. you must either specify field name to search in request url using `df` parameter

ex:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?indent=on&q=vinod&wt=json&df=text
```

OR

specify default field for the handler you using to request solr in solrconfig file.

ex: if you using /select (which is default handler). add default `text` field

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
```

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you elaborate?